# troubleshooting cascalog

Tags: clojure, hadoop

i am a new Clojure/Cascalog user trying to migrate some pig scripts, but often i get an error like the following in repl.

FlowException local step failed  cascading.flow.planner.FlowStepJob.blockOnJob (FlowStepJob.java:191)

"with-debug" gives some more information but still no root cause of the issue. Any ideas on how to improve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that the stacktraces are sometimes very unhelpful. One thing I can suggest is writing unit tests: http://sritchie.github.com/2011/09/30/testing-cascalog-with-midje.html which narrows down significantly where your actual problem lies.

If your query works for basic cases but fails on big data you can add a trap, to see what inputs are causing a failure:

```
(<- .... (:trap (hfs-textline "s3://.../errors" :sinkmode :replace)))
```

Comment: Definitely agree. Also, can paste the full stacktrace? I'd be happy to help you debug with more information. The cascalog mailing list is quite good (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/cascalog-user).

Comment: i think this is as far as it goes :), thank you for the tip. 
I dont want to bug the mail group with every issue since most if the time they are some basic errors that i can spot. But the main problem is any error seems to resolve into this exception, from parsing to casting or even some errors in the hadoop job configuration (input, output etc..), regardless of the data.

Comment: you might see a more complete stack trace if you run on a small data set locally. For example I just got this error yesterday and further up the stack it pointed into the method that was throwing an exception. When you run on a cluster the full stack trace is only available in the logs on the task node which is obviously less convenient.